# como pegar um valor de um input text?

Tags: php

dentro desse input há um número ID, eu iria utilizar essa ID para fazer uma busca no banco. como eu pego essa ID que está em um input text e "jogo" no php para eu utiliza-lo como busca? deve-se fazer algo desse tipo? abaixo:

```
                    <form method="get" action="">
                        Valor ID <input type="text" name="id-da-tabela-para-modal" id="id-da-tab-para-modal">
                    </form>
```

por enquanto está assim:

```
                <div class="modal-body">                        
                        Valor ID <input type="text" name="id-da-tabela-para-modal" id="id-da-tab-para-modal">                       
                    <?php
                    require('conexao.php');
                    $id = $_GET['id-da-tab-para-modal'];
                    $resultado = mysql_query("select * from jogo Where ID=$id");
                    echo "<table class='table'>".
                        "<thead>".
                        "<tr>".
                        "<td>ID</td>".
                        "<td>Nome</td>".
                        "<td>Conta</td>".
                        "<td>Resultado</td>".
                        "<td>Valor Digitado</td>".
                        "<td>Dificuldade</td>".
                        "<td>Score</td>".
                        "</tr>".
                        "</thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                    while($valores=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
                        echo "<tr>".
                            "<td>".$valores['ID']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$valores['nome']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$valores['conta']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$valores['resultado']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$valores['dificuldade']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$valores['totalacertos']."</td>".
                            "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</tbody></table>";
                    @mysql_close(conexao);
                    ?>
                </div>
```

não está dando certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

voce escreveu:

```
$id = $_GET['id-da-tab-para-modal'];
```

Na verdade é

```
$id = $_GET['id-da-tabela-para-modal'];
```

Afinal, o parametro name de seu input é id-da-tabela-para-modal

Comment: arrumei, não notei essa parte, mas mesmo assim não deu certo, eu tenho que criar um form com um button de submit pra poder pegar o valor do input text, não é? tem algum jeito de fazer sem o botão de "submitar"?

Comment: voce pode fazer o submit com javascript. De qualquer forma tem que submitar. O que você quer fazer? quer que a busca seja feita após pressionar uma tecla tipo enter ou que a busca seja feita enquanto o usuário digita o valor?

Comment: eu queria fazer algo desse tipo: http://jsfiddle.net/4j59z60e/16/ a minha ideia era abrir um modal com mais informação do jogador quando ele apertar o botão de "clique", a tabela anterior é só uma pequena amostra, se ele quiser ver mais informações sobre o seu jogo ele terá que clicar no botão de "clique". na tela do modal aonde há um input text é passado o ID clicado da tabela anterior, apartir deste ID irei fazer uma busca no banco de dados para saber qual informação deve-se imprimir.

Comment: Você vai precisar de ajax para fazer isso. Sugiro dar uma olhada no knockout JS. É uma ferramenta muito interessante e é bem tranquila de aprender. o Site tem um tutorial fantástico.[knockoutjs.com](http://knockoutjs.com/)

Comment: Por favor, se possível coloque sua pergunta como resolvida. Obrigado :)